# Create Xcode Project with Ruby XcodeProj

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I had this idea of making a command line utility similar to the rails setup application.
It should automatically create a Xcode project, setup unit test, setup Frank, install most used Cocoapods and setup a project structure.

There is no such thing at the moment and I would really like to have it and open source it.
I struggled around the other questions here yesterday but found nothing up to date.

I came up with the idea using [XcodeProj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) which is used by CocoaPods to generate a project containing the Pods. So it should not be impossible to do. I also found [XcodeProject](https://github.com/manifest/xcodeproject) but this seems to be read-only.

Can someone (maybe of the Cocoapods developers) give me a hint where to start, because the Xcodeproj gem is very undocumented.

Comment: This question is too broad to be easily answered. Please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to create a XcodeProject with Ruby, I can figure the other things out.

Comment: Did you mamage to get thing started? Do you have the project on github?

Comment: It was a fork from https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj I didn't manage to get it right. But I was thinking about starting it again lately.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To the best place to start to use Xcodeproj is the [`Xcodeproj::Project`](http://docs.cocoapods.org/xcodeproj/xcodeproj/project/index.html#initialize) class.

Once you open a project the Xcodeproj API allows to edit all the known attributes easily. However you need to keep in mind the following concepts:

- If an attribute is a String you can edit it directly.
- If an attribute stores an object it is necessary to ask the project to [create a new](http://docs.cocoapods.org/xcodeproj/xcodeproj/project/index.html#new) one so it is has the chance to assign an UUID.
- If you are editing an attribute which stores a list of objects it is safe only to use the method exposed by the [ObjectList](http://docs.cocoapods.org/xcodeproj/xcodeproj/project/objectlist/).
- Xcodeproj performs type checking when you assign values to attributes.

The following lightly tested code should help to get you started by creating a new project named Test with a target named App for a deployment target of iOS 6.0 that adds Class.h and Class.m file to the project, ensuring Class.m is included in the target.

```
require 'xcodeproj'

proj = Xcodeproj::Project.new
app_target = proj.new_target(:application, 'App', :ios, '6.0')
header_ref = proj.main_group.new_file('./Class.h')
implm_ref = proj.main_group.new_file('./Class.m')
app_target.add_file_references([implm_ref])

proj.save_as('Test.xcodeproj')
```

Please let us know, opening an issue, which parts of the documentation you find confusing. For more karma use a pull request.

Comment: Thanks again, I am so happy. There was just a little typo in line 4 where :iOS should be :ios this lead to an exception but I figured it out. You made my day.

Comment: @btype I submitted an edit to fix that typo. I was glad to see this via Google. For those getting started, I'd recommend learning Ruby at this point ;-) E.g. reading https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/blob/master/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb directly.

Comment: This snippet does not work with the current version of xcodeprj. The "initialize" method requires two parameters. `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)

Comment: I'm looking to create a ruby script using Xcodeproj to be able to bypass about 1 hour of Xcode fiddling to set up new targets with resources, etc... Perhaps even easier would be to copy a target, copy a scheme assigning the new target, and hopefully shave off about 45 minutes of clicking in Xcode.

Comment: @Fabio where should i run this script?